# Getting unauthorized (401) when calling App Service API from Azure Static Web App despite being Linked

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-static-web-app

I have a React app Static Web App, and it is linked to my backend API (App Service running NodeJS Express)

[image: Static Web App]

[image: Express Node API App Service]

[image: Network Request]

All requests from the SWA return as Unauthorized (401) despite it being linked to the backend. Is there anything that could be causing this?
Where can I debug this / find the logs for this?

Nothing gets logged in the Log Stream. Nothing gets logged in NodeJS (requests get blocked before). I have enabled App Service Logs and tried finding logs through FTPS to the server, but cannot find anything.

Any help appreciated. I can give more info. I respond quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had in my fetch calls from the SWA used the App Service endpoint 'https://_____.azurewebsites.net/api/' instead of just fetching from 'api/'.

Comment: Doing this is bypassing the Bring Your Own Functions feature. Per their docs, "Once linked, you can access that same endpoint through the api path from your static web app."